# Response latency time increases steadily on Jetty 6 server

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jetty

This is the basic scenario:

I have a Jetty server running on a AWS instance T2.medium.

This server contains 3 REST services: A,B and C.

My client, which is a java class running in my local eclipse

- Creates around 400 objects for service A
- After that it creates 5 B objects for each A (2000)
- Finally another 5 C objects for each B (10000).

In the end, we have around 15,000 objects created.

The execution takes 45-50 minutes to create all of the 15,000 objects.
During the first 100 requests, everything is good and beautiful, it takes around 25 to 30ms to complete each request.

After 800 requests, things are not quite good, takes around 161ms to 182ms to complete *each* request.

This time keeps increasing until it reaches 1300ms to 1321ms to complete each request. In the end, after around 10,000 requests each one takes around 3000ms to complete.

I'm not running multiple threads to do the requests.
I'm not running other services in this VM.
I'm using MySql on a RDS instance.

*Ohhh and 1 more thing, if I restart the Jetty and try to create the objects again, the behaviour keeps repeating, it starts with 30ms and gets to 3000ms. This makes me think it has something to do with the threadpool on jetty.

The code I'm using to start the jetty is:

```
    QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool(100);
    threadPool.setMinThreads(100);
    threadPool.setMaxThreads(700);
    threadPool.setMaxIdleTimeMs(3000);

    httpServer = new Server(port);
    httpServer.setThreadPool(threadPool);
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    httpServer.setHandler(contexts);

    Context root = new Context(contexts, "/", Context.SESSIONS);
    GenericWebApplicationContext springContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
    springContext.setParent(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/education/applicationContext.xml"));
    root.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE,springContext);

    Context html = new Context(contexts, "/html", Context.SESSIONS);
    ResourceHandler htmlHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    htmlHandler.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
    html.setHandler(htmlHandler);

    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(CXFServlet.class);
    root.addServlet(holder, "/rest/*");
    try {
        httpServer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and after a couple of minutes I start to see the following exception:

**

```
20:30:34.556 [509681393@qtp-1095433972-667] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - EXCEPTION 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at org.mortbay.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom(ByteArrayBuffer.java:382) ~[jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.fill(StreamEndPoint.java:114) ~[jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.fill(SocketConnector.java:198)     [jett6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:290) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228) [jetty-    6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582) [jetty-    util-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]

20:30:34.555 [867433358@qtp-1095433972-664] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - EXCEPTION 
20:30:34.563 [509681393@qtp-1095433972-667] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - EOF
```

**

Comment: You are using Jetty 6, long ago End of Life'd (in 2010). Consider upgrading (there have been over 150 releases of Jetty since then)

Comment: Do you have any idea what the garbage collector is doing during this time?

Comment: I think he is doing his job. I can see several parts showing that the GC is running and MEMORY is alwas around 10%.

Comment: I'm working on Joakim suggestion.

Comment: Both your back-end and front-end servlets have sessions enabled, is your client sending back the session cookie information?  If not you're creating 15,000 server sessions and could be slowing things down over time.  You could disable sessions for the back-end service and see if your service times remain linear

Comment: Update to version 9.2 jetty. And also the no_session parameter but still, the times are still increasing.

Comment: @FelipeFerraz if you upgraded and the latency still increases, then its not Jetty specific code or its thread pools that you should be looking at.  Its something about your code that is consuming (or not releasing) resources on that machine.  Consider an analysis of your memory during the slow periods to see what's sticking around. (eg: try jmap tools)